# Unable to read appsettings.json when debugging .net core webapi in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-webapi, vscode-debugger

When debugging in vscode I'm unable to read the `appsettings.json` in my `Startup.cs` file of my webapi project. They all return as empty/null.

My `launch.json` configuration for the webapi was generated by adding the `.NET Core Launch (console)` configuration. I also tried adding the `.NET Core Launch (web)` configuration but the same problem occurs.

The only thing I then had to change was the `"program"` setting to point to the correct dll in my project folder.

Here is my `launch.json`

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/SATestUtils.API/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/SATestUtils.API.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "console": "internalConsole"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my `tasks.json`

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/SATestUtils.Api/SATestUtils.API.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/SATestUtils.Api/SATestUtils.API.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "watch",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "run",
                "${workspaceFolder}/SATestUtils.Api/SATestUtils.API.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json` file...

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SaTestUtils"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "StorageAccountName": "devstoreaccount1",
  "AzureAD": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    "Domain": "[Domain]",
    "TenantId": "[TenantId]",
    "ClientId": "[ClientId]",
    "Scope": "[Scope]"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

When I attempt to debug the following code in my services method in `Startup.cs`

```cs
var connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];

Console.WriteLine($"Connection string = {connectionString}");
```

I simply get the following logged to the debug terminal

```
Connection string =
```

All the other settings in `appsettings.json` are also not returning. The correct settings are returned when using `dotnet run`.

What could be the issue here?

Note that I have a solution file in my working directory, then I have a folder called `SATestUtils.API` that contains the `SATestUtils.API.csproj` file for my webapi project.

Comment: Can you read the `appsettings.json` when launching the app using `dotnet build` and `dotnet run` in terminal?

Comment: Yep they are loaded correctly

Comment: Looks like the value of `cwd` is not the same as your project directory. What if you change that value from `${workspaceFolder}` to `${workspaceFolder}/SATestUtils.API`?

Comment: I had the same issue, but in addition to fixing the `cwd` entry, I also had to add `"console": "internalConsole"` to `launch.json`

Answer (score 27):

I experienced the same case, for me, what worked was what has been commented before:

Change the value of 'cwd' property in launch.json to the value of the project directory.

{
...
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
}

to

{
...
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/SATestUtils.API"
}

All the credits to Bemm...

[image]

Comment: Very helpful hint, thank you!

Comment: This is very useful, thank you so much.

Comment: OMFG. I spent an hour 'fixing' this. Can I kiss you?

Comment: I spent so much time debugging this! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify the asp net environment at the launch.json?

Something like this:

[image]